# Solve $x + y + t \le 10$

Tags: combinatorics

> For nonnegative integers, $x, y, t$ solve, $$x + y + t \le 10$$

This includes then: $x + y + t = 0$, ..., $x + y + t = 10$.

$x + y + t = 0$ has $1$ solution $= \binom{2}{2}$.

$x + y + t = 1$ has $3$ solutions, $= \binom{3}{2}$

$\cdots$

$x + y + t = 10$ has: $ $ solutions: $= \binom{12}{2}$

$$= \sum_{n=2}^{12} \binom{n}{2} = \binom{13}{3}$$

Total Solutions

Answer (score 9):

You can include a [slack variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slack_variable) $s$, and then solve $$x+y+t+s=10$$
with each variable a nonnegative integer.  You can solve this with [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), with solution $${10+4-1\choose 4-1}={13\choose 3}$$